# What is the standard way to refer to shared code in conference papers?

Tags: citations, conference, code

Say I have a github repository with the shared code and data used for that conference paper? What is the standard way to refer to it in the paper itself?

1. Write something like. The code is available in [5], and then give the linkas a reference?
2. Give the link in the paper text itself?
3. Give the link as footnotes?
4. Not mention the link in the paper itself, but send it separately as part of the submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen all of 1-3 in papers. I would favor a link in the text or footnotes over a link in the references, to underline that the code is part of the contribution of the paper. (If it isn't, e.g. because it was already presented in one of your previous papers, or because someone not on the authors list wrote a significant portion of the code, put it in the references instead.)

Definitely mention the link in the paper itself, so that readers of the paper can look it up. Also, for convenience, it's nice if the URL is a clickable link in the PDF.